# How to stop a file or folder from being indexed in GNOME?

Tags: gnome, files, directory, search, indexing

I am running Ubuntu GNOME 15.10 with GNOME 3.18, and I would like to know if I can do any of the following and if so how:

- Make it so that a folder is not indexed but leave its contents indexable (so that if I search for that folder's name in my system nothing will come up, but if I search for its contents, that will come up)
- Make it so that a folder is not indexable and nor is any of its contents (and if it contains sub-folders within it then it should recursively not allow any contents in them to be indexed nor the contents of any sub-sub-folders in the sub-folders etc, nor any of those sub-folders themselves)
- Make it so that individual files in a folder are not indexable, though not having any impact on other contents nor the parent-folder

So, are any of these variants possible? I believe the indexing program is called Tracker which indexes files and folders and their contents and allows for one to search for them on the system.

Comment: I didn't update Ubuntu 16.04 to GNOME 3.20 (so I got GNOME 3.18). I didn't find tracker-preferences But I solved installing tracker-gui
You get the preferences as well. I hope it could help.

Comment: The solutions below are for Ubuntu 16.04. Any solutions for Ubuntu 18.04?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In Ubuntu GNOME 16.04 with GNOME 3.20 there is now such an application called `Search and Indexing` (or `tracker-gui`) installed by default (if it is not installed or if you are running a previous version which does not have it pre-installed then it can be installed by running `sudo apt-get install tracker-gui`) which one can use to highly flexibly change the indexing settings with (I have blacked out some personal information in one of the screenshots):

[image: Indexing tab]

[image: Locations tab]

[image: Ignored Content tab]

[image: Control tab]

[image: System]

As can be seen from the above screenshots this covers most of the points in the question.

Comment: Seems [16.04](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&searchon=names&keywords=tracker-gui) was the last version with `tracker-gui` on official repos. Do you know of any alternative?

Comment: I'm also looking for an 18.04 alternative

Comment: Any alternative for 18.04?

Answer (score 5):

By default folders with a .trackerignore file are ignored, so it should be enough to do:

```
touch .trackerignore
```

in the folder you don't want to be indexed.

Comment: That's probably just the manual way of doing what the GUI does in the backend though,

Comment: `dconf read /org/freedesktop/tracker/miner/files/ignored-directories-with-content`

Comment: `dconf read /org/freedesktop/tracker/miner/files/ignored-directories`

Comment: Can anyone confirm if this works in Ubuntu 18.04