# How to enable Tracker (Ubuntu search file indexing) in Git repo's on the hard drive? [U17.10]

Tags: 17.10, tracker, indexing

I've noticed that Ubuntu 17.10 file indexing for search (https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Tracker I believe) skips folders that contain git repo's. I'm guessing this is because most repo's have a **large** amount of files. This is for searching from the Meta-menu/activity overview.

There are a few repo's on my PC that I use for literature, and it would be great if those were indexed. Is there a way to change this standard behavior? I can't seem to find any instructionto change nor mentions of this behavior.

I see that on systems with tracker-preferences available it is rather easy:
[How to stop a file or folder from being indexed in GNOME?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/722664/how-to-stop-a-file-or-folder-from-being-indexed-in-gnome)
On Ubuntu 17.10 I'm not sure where to find these settings, possibly using dconf?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the only way to do this currently (that I found) is apparently the dconf-editor. The key entry to be changed is: `/org.freedesktop.Tracker.Miner.Files ignored-directories-with-content`.

I changed it's value from `['.trackerignore', '.git']` to `['.trackerignore']`.