# How do I make a folder unsearchable?

Tags: gnome, directory, search, activities-overview

I am trying to make a folder unsearchable by the activities search. It used to be possible in unity when I was using that, but now that I am using Gnome, I cannot find anything that resembles it in the settings.

Thanks in advance :)

Ubuntu 19.10

Comment: Use the mkdir command to create a new folder. To make that folder hidden, add a dot (.) at the beginning of the name,

Comment: @Graham not what he is asking ;) https://askubuntu.com/a/779153/15811 is likely what you want Eirik.

Comment: @Graham By all means, that does hide it from the activities search, but I don't want the folder fully hidden. (Thanks though)

Comment: @Rinzwind Yes, that is what I am looking for. unfortunately tracker-gui does not exist for 19.10 . And the .trackerignore file did also not work :/
Thanks though.